# Kubuntu 15.04 fails to install along windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, uefi

Idk if anything else matters, but my motherboard is the Asus Maximus VIII Ranger.

It already gave me hell when installing windows 7 and now kubuntu is proving a challenge as well.

Booting from a DVD doesn't work at all, for some reason(?). A usb stick made with [This thing](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.1.exe) will boot, but it just goes to this minimal bash like thing.

The bios didn't let me disable secure boot, but deleting the keys made it go disabled. That didn't change anything though. Also, I was not running fast boot.

[I'll try the efi file thing described in one of these answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613771/installing-ubuntu-15-04-along-side-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 0):

Along with that link you posted, this link may help you as well:
https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?51442-Maximus-VI-Hero-Disabling-Secure-Boot

It seems other people have also tried to install another OS in UEFI mode, but found the same screen you've been plagued by. Generally, I disable secure boot completely when installing another OS as secure boot is supposed to prevent malware from being installed into the Boot ROM, but usually ends up blocking the user from external booting as well.